# Numerical integration of a quadratic form exponential in two variables over a rectangle

Tags: integration

Let

$$f(x,y) = \exp \left(- \frac{1}{2}a x^2 - \frac{1}{2}c y^2 + bxy \right)$$

where $a,b,c\ge 0$. I want to integrate numerically:

$$\int_{x_0}^{x_1}\mathrm{d}x \int_{y_0}^{y_1}\mathrm{d}y \, f(x,y) x^ny^m$$

where $-\infty < x_0 < x_1 < \infty$, $-\infty < y_0 < y_1 < \infty$, and $n,m\in\{0,1,2\}$.

A naive method has problems when the peak of $f(x,y)$ is far from the rectangle of integration.

Is there a method that I can use?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2693671/10063

Comment: You should not cross-post. You are not even giving time for people to answer.

Comment: Did you try using Gauss quadrature?

Comment: @nicoguaro I already posted a similar question on stats (https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/328577/5536). It did not receive any reply in over a month. That's why I was a bit more aggressive this time.

Comment: I haven't tried Gauss quadrature. But I have never programmed this myself, I don't know if a numerical package can do it. What weight function would you use?

Comment: @nicoguaro Where can I learn about Gauss quadrature in two-dimensions?

Comment: I would first check [Burden's book](https://books.google.com.co/books/about/Numerical_Analysis.html?id=zXnSxY9G2JgC&redir_esc=y) on numerical analysis.

Answer (score 2):

I just tried the integration algorithm that comes with `scipy.integrate` for double integrals (`dblquad`), and it seems to work just fine for your problem

```
from __future__ import division, print_function 
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import dblquad

a = 2
b = 2
c = 1
fun = lambda x, y: np.exp(-a/2*x**2 - b/2*y**2 + c*x*y)*x**3
inte2 = dblquad(fun, 1, 4, lambda y: -5, lambda y: 8)
print(inte2)
```

and returns

```
(0.5814009878561697, 8.012117719083942e-09)
```

The first value is the integral and the second is an estimate of the error on the integral.

Comment: Does this address the question? The question in particular asks about when the peak is far from the domain of integration, whereas your example does not seem to be peaked far outside the domain.

Comment: @user14717, since I don't have a sense of what far away means in this question I just tried a random example.